# CCAnimation multiple sets of images

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

could someone help on animating two sets of image depending on true/false condition? I am getting error message with "Interface type cannot be statically allocated" when using "CCAnimation". Here is my code:

```
//---frameSetOne

for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    [framesOne addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bird%d.png",i]]];
}

//---frameSetTwo

for (int i=5; i<=8; i++) {
    [framesTwo addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bird%d.png",i]]];
}

if ( Answer == 1 ) {

   CCAnimation _flyAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:framesOne delay:0.07f];
}

else
{

   CCAnimation _flyAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:framesTwo delay:0.07f];

}
```

Could someone help correct the issue or suggest a different way of animating multiple sets of frames/images using true or false condition?

ThanksInAdvance!

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CCAnimation* _flyAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:framesOne delay:0.07f];
```

The call to the class method animationWithSpriteFrames: method returns a CCAnimation*, not a CCAnimation.